# Laravel : load objects on many level

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following tables :

**orders** : id, etc...

**order_lines** : id, order_id, product_id, etc...

**products** : id, name, etc...

Foreign keys are defined.

My Laravel Models are defined as :

```php
class Order

 public function orderLine()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLine');
    }
```

```php
class OrderLine

public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
```

```php
class Product

public function orderLine()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderLine');
    }
```

I've tried many things, but nothing is working. Here is the best solution for me, but it's not working.

```php
class OrderController

public function show($id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $order = Order::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->with(['orderLine.product'])->findOrFail($id);
        return view('layouts/order/index', compact('order'));
    }
```

I struggle to display the following data in the view :

```php
@foreach($order->orderLine as $key => $orderLine)
<tr>
    <td>{{$orderLine->product->name}}</td>
<tr>
@endforeach
```

Product object is not loaded. I want to display the product name in the above loop.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Go step by step and see where is the problem, do only this first  ` $order = Order::where('user_id', $user->id)`  and `dd($order)` see if you get user's orders.

Comment: Have you defined a relation between orders and users?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have this error : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: .../resources/views/layouts/order/index.blade.php)

Comment: I'm able to see Order and OrderLine. It's really the 3rd level, Product, which is not loaded.

Comment: Instead of using `with()` use `load()` and see if it fixes

Comment: If there is relation between `user` and `order`. You should do something like this.
`$orders = $user->orders()->find($id)->load(['orderLine.product'])`;

Comment: I have the same issue with load().

Comment: and why are you doing `$key=>$orderLine`?
`dd($order->orderLine)` in your view file and see what are you getting?

Comment: And an advice, an `orderLine` should have many orders and an `order` should belongsTo` the orderLine

Comment: Issue is solved. It was ```php <td>{{$orderLine['product']->title}}</td> ``` instead of ```php <td>{{$orderLine->product->title}}</td> ```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do like this:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $order = Order::with(['orderLines', 'orderLines.product'])
                      ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                      ->findOrFail($id);
        return view('layouts/order/index', compact('order'));
    }
```

```
class OrderLine

public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Order::class, 'order_id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
```

```
class Order

 public function orderLines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\OrderLine::class);
    }
```

Change name of `orderLine` to `orderLines` because order has many orderLines.

And in your blade:

```
@foreach($order->orderLines as $orderLine)
<tr>
    <td>{{$orderLine['product']->title}}</td> 
<tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank @mare96. However, I still have the same issue. Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: .../resources/views/layouts/order/index.blade.php)

Comment: in `dd($order)` in array of `OrderLines` producst doesnt exists? Can you post  image of your `dd`?

Comment: Where can I post the image ? "Add another answer" or "edit my first message" ?

Comment: Take screenshot and upload it [here](https://imgur.com/upload?beta). And send link here in comment. And please open your `orderLines` and update code as in my answer..

Comment: And what is in relations inside orderLines? Are you sure of having product inside orderLines? :D

Comment: Yes, I have a product. As you can see, it's product_id 1. https://imgur.com/a/nq4HAq1

Comment: A product can have many order_lines. An order_line can have 1 product. There is a foreign key in the database.

Comment: Here is a var_dump($order->orderLines) in the view. Maybe the issue comes from "protected" instead of "public". https://imgur.com/a/YKzFA8e

Comment: Cool you have `product` in your `orderLines` now i think you need in your blade `$orderLine->product->title` because you use name and name doesn't exists..

Comment: Yeah sure, it was already ```php $orderLine->product->title``` The issue is that product object is empty.

Comment: Do you have data in `$orderLine` in foreach? Just place {{ $orderLine }} in view. Did you tried `$orderLine['product']` in your view?

Comment: Yes, I found the issue at the same time as you. It's ```php $orderLine['product']->title``` instead of ```php $orderLine->product->title``` instead of

Comment: Is there a way to use 100% object instead of the array ? Like ```php ```php $orderLine->product->title``` ?

Comment: You are welcome. :D
I will update my answer and you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dezaley and welcome to StackOverflow!
Let's investigate your problem.
As far as I can see you are selecting the model in the wrong way. Let me help you:

```php
$order = Order::where(['id' => $id, 'user_id' => $user->id])->with('orderLine.product')->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for your message. However, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from mare96, who was very friendly to help me, is working. However, I found out someting.

You can implement as (mare96 solution)

```php
public function show($id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $order = Order::with(['orderLines', 'orderLines.product'])
                      ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                      ->findOrFail($id);
        return view('layouts/order/index', compact('order'));
    }
```

```php
@foreach($order->orderLines as $orderLine)
<tr>
    <td>{{$orderLine['product']->title}}</td> 
<tr>
@endforeach
```

In the view, I don't like the array syntax "$orderLine['product']->title". The following solution without the array is also working.

Solution is below :

```php
public function show($id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $order = Order::with('orderLines', 'orderLines.product')
                      ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                      ->findOrFail($id);
        return view('layouts/order/index', compact('order'));
    }
```

```php
@foreach($order->orderLines as $orderLine)
<tr>
    <td>{{$orderLine->product->title}}</td> 
<tr>
@endforeach
```

In fact, my issue was that product was defined to null in the model, so Product was always null in the view.

```php
Class OrderLine extends Model {
     public $product = null
```

I remove line "public $product = null" and it's working as expected. Thanks to the people who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

give it a try -

```
    @foreach($order as $ordr)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$ordr->product_id->name}}</td>
    <tr>
    @endforeach
```